# R: Remove top axis title base plot

Tags: r, plot, glmnet

I want to remove or rename the "top axis title" of the following plot based on the package plotmo. Here is a short reproducible example:

```
library(glmnet)
library(plotmo)
data(mtcars)

fit <- glmnet(x=as.matrix(mtcars[,-1]), y=as.matrix(mtcars[,1]))
plot_glmnet(fit)
```

Results in:

[image]

It looks like, that the plot is made by base plot functions. May someone knows a way to Change the top axis title or remove it

Comment: If I run your code example, my output plot looks different from what you posted. There is no upper x axis title.

Comment: Edited. It was the wrong function call, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I could achieve what you desire is by editing the source code.

```
plot_glmet.edited<- plot_glmnet ## copy the function
as.list(body(plot_glmet.edited)) ## print the lines of the function
```

At the moment the code will not print a label, replace NA with any character string that you want as a title

```
    body(plot_glmet.edited)[[33]] <- substitute(
         mtext(NA, side = 3, line = 1.5, cex = par("cex") * par("cex.lab")))
```

[image]